# Turtlebot calibration returns absolute parameters not multipliers?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro#Results) says that the result of calibration by "`roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch`" are to be used to multiply the current parameters. But I've been experiencing with my 4 turtlebots that multiplication makes things worse. Instead, replacing with those returned values tends to show better result. Has there been change here or am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12121/turtlebot-calibration-returns-absolute-parameters-not-multipliers?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that you restart your turtlebot_node between runs or use dynamic reconfigure's reconfigure_gui to change the values of the parameters in the node before running.  Otherwise they will not be reread by the driver.  The default values are close to 1, so if the corrections are close to absolute when using the default parameters.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on 2011-12-27**:
After changing the params (with dynamic reconfigure or "rosparam set" command-line tool), you can "rosnode kill turtlebot_node" and it will respawn automatically with the new params. This way, no reboot is needed.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-29**:
Using dynamic reconfigure, multiplying the current values by the result values improves calibration. I also updated wiki page to clarify that rebooting node is needed. Thanks!